# Angularjs structure for reusable data visualization?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I would like to build a reusable SVG chart with Angularjs and I have a number of directive-controller related questions.

In a first instance I'd like to be able to have mark-up like this that renders a chart with form elements that affect the internal state and hence the data visualization:

```
<scatterChart></scatterChart>
```

=>

```
<div class="scatterChart">
 <div> [Form elements] </div> 
 <svg>
   [Data visualization]
 </svg> 
</div>
```

**Question 1: Controller, Directive, Module**
Does it make sense to build this as a single Directive with a separate Controller? Or would you embed the Controller in the Directive or perhaps create a Module?

**Question 2: Model/State to SVG render**
Let's say the chart controller has a an internal state like this:

```
scope.model = {
  xAxis : "xyz",
  yAxis : "abc"
}
```

A change in the model should trigger a rerendering of the chart.
What would be a DRY/proper way of sharing all of the charts user-controlled attributes between the controller and the directive?
(At the same time the directive should be able to have some dependent/private attributes.)

**Question 3: API**
How would I pass an initial state to the chart? Attributes? And if it is a 20 parameter state?

```
<scatterChart xAxis="abc"></scatterChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer 1

Embed the controller in directive, unless you want to reuse the same controller in other directive.

## Answer 2

You may create a service to store the user-controlled attributes which are shared among all charts.

## Answer 3

When there are many parameters, creating a service to store the data and inject it into your directive and controller would be a good idea.

The general idea is to decouple your data from controller and directive by creating a service.